# Fullscreen activity always showing nav ui on interaction

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen

I'm trying to make a fullscreen activity and I need it to be a bit like the web view in the pocket app where ui shows only upon a swipe down. 
I've created a default fullscreen activity in android studio and I've checked the toggle ui to false but despite that whenever I click on the screen it shows the ui.
I'm not posting code cause it's all default auto-generated by the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your manifest

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"

(https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

Comment: Still getting the same effect